# SignUp data not showing up in database in ASP.NET project

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to make a signup page in my asp.net project where I am using SQL Server for my project. But the problem is that the data is not going to the database on clicking signup button.

Here is my code which I have tried for usersignup.aspx, usersignup.aspx.cs, web.config.

**usersignup.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="usersignup.aspx.cs" Inherits="BookManagement.usersignup" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 mx-auto">
            <div class="card" style="border-radius:30px;background: #e9efef;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <center>
                                <img src="imgs/generaluser.png" style="width:90px;height:90px;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;"/>
                            </center>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <h4 style="text-align:center;">User SignUp</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <hr>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label>Full Name : </label>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Placeholder="Full Name"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label>Date Of Birth : </label>
                             <div class="form-group">
                                 <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Placeholder="Date" TextMode="Date"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label>Contact NO : </label>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Placeholder="Contact No" TextMode="Number"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label>Email  : </label>
                             <div class="form-group">
                                <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Placeholder="Email" TextMode="Email"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <label>State </label>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <asp:DropDownList class="form-control" ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">

                                    <asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="Select" />
                                    <asp:ListItem>Arunachal Pradesh</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Andra Pradesh</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Assam</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Bihar</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Chhattisgarh</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Rajasthan</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Goa</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Gujarat</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Haryana</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Himachal Pradesh</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Jammu and Kashmir</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Jharkhand</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Karnataka</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Kerela</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Madhya Pradesh</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Maharashtra</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Odisa</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Sikkim</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Punjab</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Tamil Nadu</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>West Bengal</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <label>City  : </label>
                             <div class="form-group">
                                <asp:TextBox Class="form-control" ID="TextBox6" runat="server" Placeholder="City"></asp:TextBox> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <label>PinCode  : </label>
                             <div class="form-group">
                                <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="TextBox7" runat="server" Placeholder="Pincode" TextMode="Number"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <label>Full Address: </label>
                            <div class="form-group">
                               <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Placeholder="Full Address" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                             <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-warning text-dark">New Login Credentials</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <br>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label>Member ID : </label>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <asp:TextBox Class="form-control" ID="TextBox8" runat="server" Placeholder="Member ID"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label>Password  : </label>
                             <div class="form-group">
                                <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="TextBox9" runat="server" Placeholder="Password" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col" style="width:100%;">
                            <br>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <center>
                                    <%--<asp:Button class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg" style="width:510px;" ID="SignUp" runat="server" Text="Sign Up" OnClick="SignUp_Click" />--%>
                                    <asp:Button class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg" style="width:510px;" ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="SignUp" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
                                </center>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a href="homepage.aspx"><< Back To Home</a>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

Here is my **usersignup.aspx.cs** file

```cs
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Configuration;

namespace BookManagement
{
    public partial class usersignup : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        string strcon = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkMemberExists())
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Member Already Exists.Try Again!!!');</script>");
            }
            else
            {
                signUpNewMember();
            }
        }

        bool checkMemberExists()
        {
            try
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);

                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    con.Open();
                }

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM member_master_tabel WHERE member_id='"+TextBox8.Text.Trim()+"';", con);
                
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                da.Fill(dt);

                if (dt.Rows.Count >= 1)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
                //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                Response.Write("<script>alert('signup is successful. Go to the login page.');</script>");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('" + ex.Message + "');</script>");
                return false;
            }
        }

        void signUpNewMember()
        {
            try
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);

                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    con.Open();
                }

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO member_master_tabel(full_name,dob,contact_no,email,state,city,pincode,full_address,member_id,password,account_status)" +
                         "VALUES(@full_name,@dob,@contact_no,@email,@state,@city,@pincode,@full_address,@member_id,@password,@account_status)", con);
                    //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO member_master_tabel VALUES('abhay', '11-10-2018', '1234567890', 'mail@demo.com', 'Gujarat', 'Ahmedabad', '380001', 'qwertytjfgnbvf', 'ts13', '456', 'pending');", con);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@full_name", TextBox1.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", TextBox2.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contact_no", TextBox3.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBox4.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@state", DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", TextBox6.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pincode", TextBox7.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@full_address", TextBox5.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@member_id", TextBox8.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBox9.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@account_status", "pending");

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                
                    
                Response.Write("<script>alert('signup is successful. Go to the login page.');</script>");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('" + ex.Message + "');</script>");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my **web.config** file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="con" connectionString="Data Source=PROBOOK-HP\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ebookDB;Integerated Security=true" />
        
    </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Do you get any error? Did you try debugging your server side if the code is actually executed?

Comment: When you execute your Insert query, change the line for: `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` to:

`var affectedRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` and use your debugger to see what the result of affectedRows is, `1` = inserted, `0` = nothing happened

Also, you should really change the `SELECT` statement to use parameterized queries too to avoid someone performing SQL injection there.

Comment: Also, inside of your `checkMemberExists` method, you don't ever close the connection, as you return true/false before the close statement.

Also, have you made sure you have Integrated Security enabled and setup your User under the `Security` for your DB?

Comment: Actually the problem is solved and i am feeling extremely shameful to share that there was a typing mistake in spelling in web.config file in which the spelling of Integreated Security = true  was wrong it should be Integrated Security=true